# How to disallow screen splitting if my TV monitor is not connected to my computer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have this code that allows a specific form to split to my tv monitor.

```
Dim screen As Screen
screen = screen.AllScreens(1)
QueueingWindow.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
QueueingWindow.Location = screen.Bounds.Location + New Point(100, 100)
QueueingWindow.Show()
```

But when my TV monitor is not connected, I got errors with the code in screen splitting.
How do i make my program run even I have this code.

I have an idea by myself but I don't know what to put next to my if statement to just allow the screen splitting if i have connected it to my TV monitor.

My Idea:

```
If (mytvconnectorisavailable) Then
    Dim screen As Screen
    screen = screen.AllScreens(1)
    QueueingWindow.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    QueueingWindow.Location = screen.Bounds.Location + New Point(100, 100)
    QueueingWindow.Show()
End if
```

It just only allows this code to run when my TV monitor is connected to my computer.

If i'm doing it wrong please let me know. Thanks

Comment: You haven't really thought about this very hard. You are relying on `AllScreens` having a second element so how is it not obvious that you need to check that `AllScreens` has at least 2 elements?

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I have figure it out my problem. I used ``Screen.AllScreens.Length = 2``

Answer (score 0):

```
If Screen.AllScreens.Length = 2 Then
    Dim screen As Screen
    screen = screen.AllScreens(1)
    QueueingWindow.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    QueueingWindow.Location = screen.Bounds.Location + New Point(100, 100)
    QueueingWindow.Show()
End if
```